# React onClick event in array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Edit:** I have included the full code for better clarity

I am not sure if this is possible. I am trying to pass an onClick event via props but the click event does not work.

The parent component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { getProductsById } from '../api/get'
import Product from './Product'
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types'
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie'

class Cart extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
         const { cookies } = props;
            this.state = {
            prods: cookies.get('uircartprods') || '',
            collapsed: true,
            total: 0,
        }
        this.expand = this.expand.bind(this)
        this.p = [];
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getCartProducts()
    }
    handleClick = (o) => {
        this.p.push(o.id)
        const { cookies } = this.props
        cookies.set('uircartprods', this.p.toString(), { path: '/' , sameSite: true})
        this.setState({prods: this.p })
        console.log('click')
    }
    getCartProducts = async () => {
        let products = []
        if (this.state.prods !== '') {
            const ts = this.state.prods.split(',')
            for (var x = 0; x < ts.length; x++) {
                var p = await getProductsById(ts[x])
                var importedProducts = JSON.parse(p)
                importedProducts.map(product => {
                    const prod = <Product key={product.id} product={product} handler={() => this.handleClick(product)} />
                    products.push(prod)
                })
            }
            this.setState({products: products})
        }
    }
    expand(event) {
        this.setState({collapsed: !this.state.collapsed})
    }
    handleCheckout() {
        console.log('checkout clicked')
    }
  render() {
    return (
            <div className={this.state.collapsed ? 'collapsed' : ''}>
                <h6>Your cart</h6>
                <p className={this.state.prods.length ? 'hidden' : ''}>Your cart is empty</p>
                {this.state.products}
                <h6>Total: {this.props.total}</h6>
                <button onClick={this.handleCheckout} className={this.state.prods.length ? '' : 'hidden' }>Checkout</button>
                <img src="./images/paypal.png" className="paypal" alt="Paypal" />
                <a className="minify" onClick={this.expand} alt="My cart"></a>
                <span className={this.state.prods.length ? 'pulse' : 'hidden'}>{this.state.prods.length}</span>
            </div>
        )
  }
}
    
export default withCookies(Cart)
```

The Product component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showDetails: false,
            showModal: false,
            cart: []
        }
        this.imgPath = './images/catalog/'
    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="Product">
            <section>
                <img src={this.imgPath + this.props.product.image} />
            </section>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <h2>{this.props.product.title}</h2>
                    <h3>{this.props.product.artist}</h3>
                    <p>Product: {this.props.product.product_type}</p>
                    <h4>&#36;{this.props.product.price}</h4>
                    <button className="button" 
                    id={this.props.product.id} onClick={this.props.handler}>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Product
```

If I log this.props.handler I get undefined. Everything works apart from the click handler, I was wondering if it might have something to with the async function. I am very new to React, there are still some concepts I'm not sure about, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `handler` is creating a new function instead of passing a function. It should be `handler={this.handleClick}`

Comment: Can you post the complete code? There appear to be missing parts. What is importedProducts? What do you intent to do with handleClick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I see a few issues here.

First, there is no need to call `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)` in the constructor, because you are using an arrow function. Arrow functions do not have a `this` context, and instead, accessing `this` inside your function will use the parent `this` found in the Class.

Secondly, it is wrong to store components in state. Instead, map your importedProducts inside the render function.

Thirdly, the issue with your handler is that `this.props.handler` doesn't actually call `handleClick`. You will notice in the definition `handler={(product) => this.handleClick}` it is returning the function to the caller, but not actually calling the function.

Try this instead.

```js
class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="button" id={this.props.product.id} onClick={this.props.handler}>
          Add to cart
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Product;
```

```js
import Product from './Product'

class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick = (o) => {
    console.log('click');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {importedProducts.map((product) => {
          return <Product key={product.id} product={product} handler={() => this.handleClick(product)} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cart;
```